# Create Wordpress category dynamically

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, categories

I have more than 15 Category ,

And i have a custom taxonomy "classroom",

Is there any way to Create those categories automatically when i activate plugin?

Answer (score 0):

When the plugin is activated, you can activate the custom taxonomy creation code.

You can create a scenario like this.

Plugin activated - Custom Taxonomy created - Category information is imported via the xml file you created before

---

You can export your taxonomy data (Tools - Export) and u have xml file.

And than follow this import code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902413/how-import-xml-data-into-wordpress-programatically

Comment: That's what OP wants to do I think yes. Does code to import categories from XML already exist? How do you call it? What specifically do you hook it to?

Comment: can you edit your original answer and delete this one, or vice versa? This isn't a discussion forum thread so these aren't replies, and they will change order based on votes. Your solution should be a singular self contained solution/answer, not a reply

Comment: I've deleted your other answer and edited it on to the end of this one, if you have more to add you should use the `Edit` link to update it